# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS defined in environment but not recognized when authenticating

Tags: google-authentication

I am beginner in Python. I am trying to build a sentiment analysis engine using Google's Natural Language API. I have followed their instructions, starting from creating a project to downloading the service account key. I have also read all the relevant posts here and in other forums, including Google's Github. However, the test run does not work as it says that the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS are not defined, despite executing $ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="PATH/service-account.json"

I checked with set | grep GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and I got the right response.

I checked the environment (printenv) and I see that the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS are included there with the right path.

I have also tried to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS on my editor but it says the GOOGLE_APPLICATION is not defined:
import os
os.environ[GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS]='/Users/jbarrigapartarrieu/Python/env/lib/Python3.7/service-account.json'
print(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])

I am using Mac OS Sierra 10.13.6 and Python 3.7

Many thanks for all the help in advance!

Image of code:

Comment: please provide the [mcve] by posting the code that you are trying to run. Please also include the command that you use to run the script. Also, the problem with setting env var in code is that you didn't put var name in quotes: `os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = ...`

Comment: Thank you, I was missing that and now it is working by assigning the account credentials on the actual code. Thank you! Sorry, first time writing something on Stackoverflow :-)